# How to disable or delete guest user account, from my MacBook Pro

Tags: osx, macintosh

In "Users and Groups", I see a "Guest User" listed there, as "Login only". However I do not want this user account. When I try to uncheck the "Allow guests to login this computer" for this user, I found that checkbox is greyed out.

So how can I disable or delete the guest user from my Macbook?

I have FileVault and Find my Mac enabled, but even after I disabled them, that checkbox is still grey out!

The reason I want to disable or delete guest user is that I found the process `parentalcontrolsd` occupies a lot of CPU, I searched and found it seems I need to disable or delete guest user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This questions answers describe how the user accounts on OSX are managed. Perhaps you can delete the guest user using that info.

https://superuser.com/questions/191330/users-in-etc-passwd-on-mac-os-x